# <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Error unable to save iid-token to keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"

Tags: ios, firebase, token, keychain

I have this error in my phone device.
I already have enable keychain capabilities, but it doesnt work.

At the first launch application, the fcm sdk return the token, but after disconnect, and reconnect the Api return me nil in the token and this message error above is shown.

The token always return nil :

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]
```

after the message error, next log error :

Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=502 "(null)"

and next log error :

Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries

It occurs when i disconnect and reconnect using fcm Api :

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
```

and after foreground :

```
 [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
}];
```

I already enable keychain capabilities !

Answer (score 1):

By default your "Keychain Capabilites" is turned to OFF, this is giving you the keychain error,

Simply go into your project navigator, then under the capabilites tab go scroll down to Keychain Sharing and switch it to ON. This should help you.